# Regex return single match starting from beginning of line

Tags: regex

I have text that looks something like this (but much uglier of course):

```
On 9/02/2019, 9/03/2019 and 9/05/2019 this thing happened
```

and I would like to regex capture anything related to the date

```
On 9/02/2019, 9/03/2019 and 9/05/2019
```

Using regex

```
([a-zA-Z ]{0,5}(?:\d+\/)+\d+\s*(?:,|and|\s)+)
```

this seems to work fine (allowing for the first 5 characters of string to be leading words).

But when I tell it I only want to start at the beginning of the string with

```
^([a-zA-Z ]{0,5}(?:\d+\/)+\d+\s*(?:,|and|\s)+)
```

It only captures `On 9/02/2019,`.

Strings that begin with the event followed by the date I will need to treat differently

```
He was walking when he encountered a stray dog on 9/2/19
```

https://regex101.com/r/p4H10Z/1

Comment: The regexp only matches one date at a time. Without the anchor, it matches 3 times for the 3 different dates. But with the anchor it can only match the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to figure out how to make it a single match. But now I see, thank you: `^([a-zA-Z ]{0,5}((?:\d+\/)+\d+\s*(?:,|and|\s)+)+)`

Comment: You need to define what to repeat. A pattern like `^On(?:(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?|\s+and\s+)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})+` might work. See https://regex101.com/r/Ir0gMp/1

Comment: @FrancisSmart You can post that as an answer.

Comment: Might be worth deleting this question since seems it was a simple user error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the rapid responses. I was hoping to figure out how to make it a single match. Now I see. Grouping all of the date matches in another group that can be repeated does the job.

```
^([a-zA-Z ]{0,5}((?:\d+\/)+\d+\s*(?:,|and|\s)+)+)
```